# Xcode Export Mac App without Developer Program

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing

I am positive that in the past, it has been possible to export an *unsigned* Mac app from Xcode without enrolling in the Developer Program. However, now I am getting this screen:

[image: WHY?]

**It is NOT signed.** Here's a screenshot of my configuration:

[image: Config]

So, the question is, why is the "Export..." button greyed out?

Comment: If it's not signed, you shouldn't need to export it. Just do a release build, and look in your DerivedData folder (likely `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`) for your Products folder. You'll see the .app file in there. Zip it up, or make a .DMG file for it and you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: I wrote this years ago, but to clarify (if I remember correctly), the issue was a conflict between the project-wide build settings and the build settings for the particular target. The solution is to remember when you use the project editor, you have to highlight the right entry in the projects/targets list, remember that bolded settings override the default, and the final value is determined by the most specific override. If you are stuck, select the "Levels" view at the top of the "Build Settings" tab and it will show how each setting is determined. "Levels" mode is ordered left to right in order of decreasing precedence; the leftmost column is the final value, and the rightmost is the default. See [the docs](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.0/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/deva3af9b6ba) for more info.

---

Actually, it was signed.

The problem lies in the way Xcode manages code signing settings. Simply setting the "Signing" option to "None" in the "Identity" section of the project configuration does not completely change it, and causes tools like CocoaPods to still attempt to sign it.

In order to completely disable code signing, you must set up the "Code Signing Identity" part of your Build Settings like this:

[image: Why is disabling code signing so hard???]